# Looking for a sci-fi movie about astronauts helping aliens fix their craft on the moon

Tags: story-identification, movie, moon

It may be  1 movie or a combination of 2 or more. I would have watched this movie somewhere in the 60's or 70's.

The plot follows astronauts that go to the moon and, while there, discover a disabled alien craft that needs to be repaired. The aliens, who look human, need the assistance of the astronauts so the aliens help the astronauts get back to earth so they can get the parts they need to fix their craft.

The aliens craft was a large round shape and I believe there were robots/androids also inside the alien craft.

Comment: [Star Pilot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058859/)?

Answer (score 2):

This is ***[Mission Stardust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Stardust)***.

> This film is based on the popular pulp novel series Perry Rhodan. The
>   story begins with the spacecraft Stardust being launched from Earth to
>   explore the moon in an attempt to discover new deposits of a new
>   element, much more powerful than Uranium or any other source of energy
>   ever discovered. The plot takes a split approach with the Stardust
>   being taken over by a mysterious force, causing it to land on the Dark
>   side of the Moon, and out of contact with Earth. Meanwhile on earth,
>   an organized crime boss has planted an agent amongst the crew of the
>   Stardust to attempt to take the energy source somehow, if it is found.
>   Soon Perry Rhodan and his crew discover an alien starship which has
>   had to make an emergency landing on the Moon due to technical
>   problems. The ship is commanded by the Alien Crest and the beautiful
>   captain Thora. They are informed that Crest, one of the last great
>   scientists of their dying civilization is very ill.

Comment: Yes, this was it, thanks, I have been looking for this for years, I must have been 4-5 years old when I watched this and it seemed so high-tech, but it has everything I remember,......